# Google oauth2 login server 'Connection Refused" in dev

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin

I'm having a problem with google login implementation. Everything works well in local but after pushing app to remote server - in dev , google login is not working. I'm receiving an error :

[image]

Here is my local configuration :

```
application-local.yml

    app:
      tokenSecret: xxx
      tokenExpirationMsec: 864000000
      authorizedRedirectUris:
        - http://localhost:3000/oauth2/redirect
```

here the same for dev :

```
application-dev.yml

app:
  tokenSecret: xxx
  tokenExpirationMsec: 864000000
  authorizedRedirectUris:
    - http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:3000/oauth2/redirect
```

There's also implementation on client side. In local looks like this :

```
export const API_BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8080';
export const OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:8080/oauth2/redirect'
export const GOOGLE_AUTH_URL = API_BASE_URL + '/oauth2/authorize/google?redirect_uri=' + OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI;
```

Same implementation for dev env :

```
export const API_BASE_URL = 'http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:8080';
export const OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI = 'http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:8080/oauth2/redirect'
export const GOOGLE_AUTH_URL = API_BASE_URL + '/oauth2/authorize/google?redirect_uri=' + OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI;
```

Of course there also configuration in Google dev console :

[image]

I think I also have to set Authorized JavaScript origin but I cannot use server address - looks I need domain for that(really ??). I lost 2 days trying to find wheres the issue. Any idea, please ? Maybe some security reasons ? Let me add that server needs ssh verification. Thanks for your help in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Your redirect uri and JavaScript origin need to be https.

Sending authorization though a non encrypted connection would not be very secure.